# protected affectation operator and public copy-ctor

Tags: c++, copy

**Firstly:**

What are the possible reasons for which a class have is:

- `operator =` protected
- `copy-ctor` public ?

**Secondly**:

Consider the following design:

```
class WeirdDesign
{
  public :
    WeirdDesign(const WeirdDesign& ){}

  protected:
    WeirdDesign& operator=(const WeirdDesign&){}
};

struct A
{
  typedef std::vector<WeirdDesign> mytype;

  void method(const mytype& elements)
  {
    // access to elements
  }
};

class B
{ 
   void inserter()
   {
      std::unordered_map < std::string,  A::mytype > mymap;
      mymap.insert(std::make_pair("0", A::mytype())); //fail at linking

      A().method(mymap.find("0")->second);
   }
};
```

When I try to insert a element inside `B::mymap_`, the linker fail to resolve the `operator=` of `WeirdDesign` ? Why ?

Comment: If it's protected, you can subclass and provide a public wrapper of this protected method.

Comment: Telling us where you saw such a pattern might give us a lead…

Comment: @Potatoswatter:inside a tierce library mfast

Comment: @Guillaume07 I mean,  what kind of class.

Comment: sorry I am not the author of this client code, I have made a mistake, I edit again.

Comment: Possibly so that the class in question can be immutable, but can also be inherited by a mutable subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Some operations of standard containers require that the value type will be CopyAssignable. An example of such an operattion of std::vector is member function `insert`.

The same is valid for standard associative containers. In paragraph #7 of section 23.2.4 Associative containers of the C++ Standard there is note

> [ Note: For example, in some cases key_type and mapped_type are
>   required to be CopyAssignable even though the associated value_type,
>   pair, is not CopyAssignable. —end note ]